# Starting and stopping container instances in-between task definitions on ECS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

To reduce costs I would like to stop and start an container instance in a cluster in-between tasks. The task run every now and again so doesn't seem efficient keeping an EC2 running in-between.

What is the best way to allow this?

I have looked into lambda functions triggered by a cloudwatch scheduler and also thought about autoscaling.

Comment: Have you tried autoscaling with task/containers and instances?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon doesn't make this incredibly straight-forward (though, they're trying to with [Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-fargate/)). The best solution for now (if you're not in a region where Fargate is an option) is to try to keep your desired task count in line with your desired instance count on an autoscaling group.

The way we have it setup is through Lambda, triggering based on Autoscaling events (pretty easy to setup). The least trivial part about this is the Lambda script, though it's not incredibly difficult. Add tags to your ASG that help identify what cluster / service it's associated with. When a scaling event triggers your script, just have your script describe the ASG that triggered it, look for the cluster / service that's in the tags, and updated the desired count of that service:

```
asgDetail = paginator_describe_asg.paginate(
    AutoScalingGroupNames=[
        asgName,
    ]
)

# set service desired count equal to ASG desired capacity
newDesiredCount = iter(asgDetail).next()['AutoScalingGroups'][0]['DesiredCapacity']
response = client_ecs.update_service(
    cluster = <ecs cluster>,
    desiredCount = newDesiredCount,
    service = <ecs service>
)
```

The reason you shouldn't rely on CloudWatch for this is because it doesn't do a great job at granular scaling. What I mean is, the CPU that CloudWatch monitors on your ASG is the *overall group average* (I think). So the scenario we ran into was as follows:

- CloudWatch detects **hosts** are at 90%, desired is 70%
- CloudWatch launches 4 hosts
- Service detects **tasks** are at 85%, desired is 70%
- Service launches new task
- Service detects **tasks** are at 80%, desired is 70%
- Service launches new task
- Service detects **tasks** are at 75%, desired is 70%
- Service launches new task
- Service detects **tasks** are at 70%, no action

While this is a trivial example, it's easy to see how the number of instances get out of sync from the number of tasks actually running (i.e., you may end up with a host sitting idle because ECS doesn't detect that it needs more capacity).

Could we just scale up 3 hosts? Sure, but ECS might still only place 2 tasks (depending on how the usage is per task). Could we scale one host at a time? Sure, but then it's pretty difficult to account for bursts.

All that to say, the best solution I can recommend for now is to have a Lambda script help keep your ASG instance count == your ECS service desired task count.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, see answer for my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to create a lambda function that starts the instance and on container instance start a task is ran. Then I have a cloud watch event watching for the task changing status to STOPPED which triggers another lambda that stops the instance.